# Running pip inside conda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda, environment

There are a couple of questions connected to the pip/conda interation, but this is a very concrete one,

When a given conda environment is activated in the terminal,

```
(my_env) user@box:~$
```

if I run `pip`, for example,

```
pip3 install pandas==0.21.0
```

will this work within the environment `my_env`?

Comment: If you run `pip`, but not if you run `pip3`. Conda doesn't install aliases for `pip` because it is already isolated in the environment. `pip3` likely points back to another install on your system. That said, try to avoid doing this, [as per the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as it is activated.

Everything you do when your environment is activated keeps inside of it.

Try to install another library with your environment activated (like `black` library for example) and check if exists in a global environment with `pip show black`.

Certainly, it won't exist in global.

Keep in mind that the conda global environment already comes with a lot of installed packages. You could check them with `pip freeze`.